# switch route in web.php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've 2 routes in my web.php

1)  `Route::get('/{url}', 'MenuController@menu');`

which provide url :

- /menu

2) `Route::get('/{name}', 'HomeSlideviewController@index')->name('promotiondetail');`

which provide url :

- /menu (different page but same name in route 1)
- /food

I want to use 2 route if route = same name I want to use route 1 if route 1 dont have url It will use route 2 . In web.php is their anyway to do something like

```
if(Route::get('/{url}', 'MenuController@menu')) is null use

`Route::get('/{name}', 'HomeSlideviewController@index')->name('promotiondetail');`
```

now in my web.php I do this

```
 Route::get('/{url}', 'MenuController@menu');
 Route::get('/{name}', 'HomeSlideviewController@index')->name('promotiondetail');
```

when I go /food It will go page not found.

**UPDATE**

In my controller I try this

```
try {
    // if find url
}
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //if not find url
    return redirect()->route('promotiondetail', $url);
}
```

and It return Error redirected you too many times

**UPDATE 3**

$url = food

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that when you use

```
Route::get('/{url}', 'MenuController@menu');
Route::get('/{name}', 'HomeSlideviewController@index')->name('promotiondetail');
```

you are having the same request because {url} or {name} are optional parameters and what happens is that it will always match the first case. The best solution for you can be using this part of code:

```
Route::get('/menu', 'MenuController@menu');
Route::get('/{name}', 'HomeSlideviewController@index')->name('promotiondetail');
```

You should always have the one with only optional parameters last, because otherwise it will always be executed first because it will be matching. And what you should remember is that using `/{name}` it will match anything, it is like a variable and can contain a number also it can be a string, for instance a url might be `domain/{anything}`. If you use `/name` it will match only if you are having `domain/name` as request.

You might want to read [Laravel routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing) for more information about routing.

Comment: well., their is no way to use {url} , {name} right ?

Comment: when you are using {url} and {name} it will always match the first case because they are optional for instance {url} is covering in the url any word or anything, what you can do is use '/url', then '/name' or if you want to pass some optional params you should go for '/name/{name}' and '/url/{url}'

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that both routes are essentially the same, /{something}.

You have a couple of solutions.
Firstly, sort out your routes, make them slightly different so they don't match each other and correct the order.
For example;

```
Route::get('/promo/{name}', 'HomeSlideviewController@index')->name('promotiondetail');
Route::get('/{url}', 'MenuController@menu')->name('menu');
```

Another solution that may work for you is to place the promotiondetail route first, and do a check in that for the same name, if not then redirect to the other controller. So in your index function of HomeSlideviewController, try something like;

```
public function index($name) {
    if ($name !== 'whatever you want it not to be') {
        return redirect()->route('menu);
    }
    // continue
}
```

Comment: thank I think I need the 2nd one because I dnt want to use /promo/

Comment: well I try the 2nd one It said Missing required parameter /{url} How can i pass parameter with route

Comment: @test1321 when you redirect to promotiondetail the line should be `return redirect()->route('promotiondetail', ['name' => $url]);`